# Executing a Python Script with Metasploit

Tags: python, metasploit

I am trying to run vulnerability testing for a class and the first line of code in the script is:

from metasploit.msfrpc import MsfRpcClient

However, when I try to run the program, I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'metasploit'"

I am running on Kali Linux; metasploit comes standard, but either I am doing something wrong or am missing a module. Has anyone run into this and can maybe suggest a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

first,
pip3 install --user pymetasploit3
$ msfrpcd -P yourpassword -S

and then in python,

from pymetasploit3.msfrpc import MsfRpcClient

It can work. Good luck.